# How can I change a shader alpha color in script?

Tags: unity, c#

[image: Shader]

How can I get access to the Main Color and change the alpha color ?
How do I know what is the variable of the main color in the shader code ?

If it's Main Color in the Inspector then this is the parameter I should get in the script "Main Color" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the colour is exposed with the name `_Color` in the shader code (most defaults are), then you can access it with [material.color](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-color.html), using a reference to the material instance you want to change, something like this:

```
var renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
// This getter copies the material to a local instance, 
// so cache it and remember to clean it up when you're done with it.
_cachedMaterial = renderer.material;

// Read, modify the alpha, and write back to the material.
Color color = _cachedMaterial.color;
color.a = 0.5f;
_cachedMaterial.color = color;
```

If it has a different name in the shader code, you can use [material.GetColor()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.GetColor.html) or [material.SetColor()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetColor.html), passing either the internal name of the colour variable as a string, or an integer ID retrieved via [Shader.PropertyToID()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Shader.PropertyToID.html).

Please remember to take at least a cursory search through the available API documentation or tutorials for basic questions like this - you'll often find your own answer far faster than it takes someone else to type it up for you.

Comment: And if performance is a concern (as changing `material.color` will clone the material) you can use [`MaterialPropertyBlock`s](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyBlock.html)